# Best builtin way for footer generation

Tags: blocks

What would be the drupal 7 options to generate the footer links?

Writing the links by hand could lead to 404 errors if links change...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly simple:

1. Create a menu at http://mysite.com/admin/structure/menu/add
2. Add some links to it
3. Go to http://mysite.com/admin/structure/block and assign the automatically generated block for your new menu to your theme's footer region.

If your theme doesn't have a footer region you can add one by adding a line like the following to the theme's `.info` file:

```
regions[footer] = Footer
```

And then edit `page.tpl.php` to add the new region wherever it sits best in your HTML:

```
<?php echo render($page['footer']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clive's answer is great if you want a footer where admins define the footer links manually. I usually prefer auto-generated footers using various Views blocks (I find Views more flexible than anything specific to footers would be).

If you want a footer that automatically tracks an existing menu but presents it differently, look into one of the many modules that put menu data into views. I've had (so far) good experiences with [Menu Node Views](http://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views) despite it not having a stable release yet.